# Sending Requests To Mobile Sites Using HttpClient

Tags: http, asynchronous, httpclient

I am new to Task-based programming and this new `HttpClient` class, but I read the examples and documentation on the MSDN and have a basic understanding of both. I tried to create a basic application that sends an `async` request, but it has already failed. It seems to be a problem with the URL, but have a look at the code first:

```
    public static async void ScrapeDailyRaces()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        Stream myStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://mobile.bet365.com/");
    }
```

When I tried to replace the URL with `http://www.google.com`, and also `https://www.google.com`, but they both worked so it isn't a problem with `https`.  I also tried adding `www` to the faulty URL, resulting in `https://www.mobile.bet365.com/`, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Exception details: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive." and "An error occurred while sending the request."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone ran into the same problem, I fixed it by adding a user agent to the request using the following:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like you're scraping them and they don't like that. Don't they offer an API?

Comment: No they don't. It is just a test, I am not doing anything wrong.